# How do I programmatically show the waiting icon on Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How do I programmatically show the waiting icon on Windows Mobile 6?

It should be easy to do, but I could not google it since there are so many waiting icon replacements out there... :-)

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is somewhat useful:

```
class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    public WaitCursor()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

It allows you to make use of "using" blocks to return to the default cursor even if you have an exception or a return:

```
public Foo()
{
    using (var c = new WaitCursor())
    {
       // do long-running stuff
       // when we exit the using block, the cursor will return to the default state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean the wait cursor?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```